# Exception RuntimeError in Rack application object Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key even after adding the secret key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, passenger

While deploying my rails app on aws intance I got the following error.I am not able to figure out the problem. I am using nginx and passenger. Searched the Internet but still not found any solution. Following is the content of error log file.

```
App 10537 stdout:
App 10537 stderr:  --> Compiling passenger_native_support.so for the current Ruby interpreter...
App 10537 stderr:
App 10537 stderr:      (set PASSENGER_COMPILE_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 10537 stderr:
App 10537 stderr:  --> Downloading precompiled passenger_native_support.so for the current Ruby interpreter...
App 10537 stderr:
App 10537 stderr:      (set PASSENGER_DOWNLOAD_NATIVE_SUPPORT_BINARY=0 to disable)
App 10537 stderr:
App 10537 stderr:      Could not download https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.0.13/rubyext-ruby-2.2.0-x8$
App 10537 stderr:      Trying next mirror...
App 10537 stderr:      Could not download https://s3.amazonaws.com/phusion-passenger/binaries/passenger/by_release/5.0.13/rubyext-ruby-2.2.0-x$
App 10537 stderr:  --> Continuing without passenger_native_support.so.
App 10537 stderr: Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /usr/share/nginx/html/trans-info/log/production.log exists and is$
App 10560 stdout:
App 10537 stderr: [ 2015-07-10 22:00:38.0639 10560/0x00000000e1da20(Worker 1) utils.rb:85 ]: *** Exception RuntimeError in Rack application ob$
App 10537 stderr:       from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:520:in `validate_secret_key_config$
App 10537 stderr:       from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:246:in `env_config'
App 10537 stderr:       from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
App 10537 stderr:       from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
App 10537 stderr:       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:94:in `process_request'
App 10537 stderr:       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:149:in `accept_and_process_next_req$
App 10537 stderr:       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
App 10537 stderr:       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:415:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
App 10537 stderr:       from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:111:in `block in create_thread_and_abort_on_exception'
[ 2015-07-10 22:00:38.0641 10511/7fdb5a226700 age/Cor/Req/Utils.cpp:95 ]: [Client 1-1] Sending 502 response: application did not send a comple$
App 10567 stdout:
App 10574 stdout:
```

The problem is regarding the secret key I guess. I tried to do the following things to set the secret key for production environment. But still it doesn't solve the problem.

```
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=<rake secret>
ruby -e 'p ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]'
```

Comment: Maybe your app is being run as the wrong user? See this page for more information: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/nginx/user_sandboxing.html

Comment: Also, how does your config.yml look like? Are you sure you specified the secret key in the section that matches your environment name?

Comment: @Hongli Are you talking about config.ru file?

Answer (score 1):

I  fixed this problem in Rails 4.2.3 by updating file inside yourapp/config/secrets.yml with generated `rake secret` key

You will see in that file that development and test environment line have random  generated key like :

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 0d61219baac693241c55f0d5e32casdasdasdasdas3adc915d60f303bb55bfe0f9c7d3d7c77914ebba3924529b0f55fa2ddc2f861052d9b7bb25ea5d1asdasdasdasdas8d857ed2dc8df0cdccd3a

test:
  secret_key_base: 12df598106f9f303d34c087aasdasdas85f7439b86e881788340c85e932aa14579661c0606b29ac9ff6438619e65b8ac0abd201e7asdasdasdsad2555d77d975a8c522032e8bfa956bb3

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
production:
  secret_key_base: 5b2555128d5b97181d2a65aeasdasdasddd2cb4d7df37b49dd97de7ebb2305d56a1c649be86bff3fc48536543eead7091018e5casdasdasdasdasd5c563c6ca02771e1b5f99cbc35db886cd9
```

and production had something like :

production:
secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>

So I changed that line with `rake secret` command  generated key

```
production:
  secret_key_base: 5b2555128d5b97181d2a65aeasdasdasddd2cb4d7df37b49dd97de7ebb2305d56a1c649be86bff3fc48536543eead7091018e5casdasdasdasdasd5c563c6ca02771e1b5f99cbc35db886cd9
```

Comment: I think it is not a good practice to put the secret key directly in the file secret.yml file. Even I generated the key with rake secret command but unfortunately it didn't work.